# windows 10 ssd boots in one pc but not in another

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

on the pc where the ssd wont boot, it seems like it will boot but it just shows the loading screen though the windows logo disappears after a while nothing else changes
[image]

machine history
bought the laptop a year ago
replaced hdd with ssd in december (using samsung software to copy the drive)
around a month ago it stopped booting in that laptop, but it still boots normally when i plug it in to a different laptop (i think it happened right after a windows update)

so, does anyone know what the cause of that could be? and more importantly: can anyone help me fix my problem?

Comment: Could be one of Microsoft's dreaded drivers that got downloaded via Windows Update. Try to start Windows in *improvised* mode (which skips loading most drivers) and go back to a restore point before the update. Alternatively, boot from CD/USB and employ Windows's restore tools: autocorrect or go back to a restore point.

Comment: i already tried restore and the like, i even tried chkdsk c:/f... do you mean safe mode (i'll try it)? what do you mean my dreaded drivers? i have a windows install usb stick, what should i do with that?

Comment: safe mode is not accessible not even through command prompt (set {default} safeboot minimal)

Comment: Windows Update not only updates the operating system but also installs "updated" drivers from Microsoft. That may explain why Windows boots on one system and not on another, and that's why I suggested going back to a restore point before the update that likely did the mess. You said you already tried that: what happened? Did yo have no restore points or the restore was successful but the problem persists?

Comment: i'll retry restore and let you know. about drivers, 14 were modified around that time and 6 were created. the 6 created are avira usb feature, microsoft basic render, secure digital bus, usb xhci, directx graphics kernel and network driver interface specification, the 14 modded are wdi driver framework, dfs namespace client driver, nvdmm-n disk,usb mass storage class, storage spaces, kernel cryptography next generation, multiple unc provider, nt file system, storage class memory bus, microsoft nvm express storport miniport,avira minifilter/ security enhancement/ usb filter/ usb feature

Comment: there is no restore point, no image, startup recovery doesnt work and it cant go back to previous build

Comment: set {default} safeboot minimal BUT ON SYSTEM BCD ON HDD/SSD!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: snayob, can you please explain what you were trying to say?